# Making an OAuth signed POST request over SSL from app engine

Tags: java, google-app-engine

Ran into an interesting issue with google app engine (on the java runtime). From within an app engine task/view, I'm attempting to contact an external webservice API.

The external API uses OAuth for authentication and only accepts requests over SSL. The particular method I'm calling is a POST request.

**Option 1:** Use the AppEngine URLFetch Service. However, I don't see a way to do the OAuth signing. URL Fetch uses the java.net HttpURLConnection, which streams it's requests, precluding signing. My go-to java OAuth library is [oauth-signpost](http://code.google.com/p/oauth-signpost/), but it doesn't support java.net for this reason. Is there an OAuth library that is compatible with HttpURLConnection?

**Option 2:** Use another URL fetching library. My favorite HTTP library is the [apache commons HTTP library](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/index.html). However, this causes a problem when using SSL, since javax.ssl is prohibited by the app engine sandbox. I get the following error attempting to use the apache library over SSL:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax.net.ssl.KeyManagerFactory is a restricted class. Please see the Google App Engine developer's guide for more details.
at javax.net.ssl.KeyManagerFactory.<clinit>(KeyManagerFactory.java)
at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory.createSSLContext(SSLSocketFactory.java:223)
```

I assume because you can't open sockets directly.

This is all a sad confluence of OAuth / POSTs / SSL / App engine which I don't quite see a way out of. Would love to hear any and all suggestions =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. [`google-oauth-java-client`](http://code.google.com/p/google-oauth-java-client/)
2. [HttpClient should work in AppEngine](http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/wiki/WillItPlayInJava), if you use custom ConnectionManager that wraps UrlFetch. Details are [here](http://esxx.blogspot.com/2009/06/using-apaches-httpclient-on-google-app.html) and [here](http://peterkenji.blogspot.com/2009/08/using-apache-httpclient-4-with-google.html).

Comment: I have the same problem and prefer option 1 here, since I don't understand the funny packaging users of option 2 are doing. But I'm also a bit stuck on how exactly I'm supposed to sign an HTTP request using google-oauth-java-client.

Their docs (http://code.google.com/p/google-oauth-java-client/wiki/OAuth1) point to some OAuthSigner implementations, but neither knows how to sign an HTTP request.